# IMap read mail content

Tags: java

I try get the content of the mail but all it print is
`javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@2d6eabae`

My code:

```
for (final Message message : inbox.getMessages())
            {
                final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\<([^)]+)\\>").matcher(message.getFrom()[0].toString());
                
                if (!matcher.find() || !matcher.group(1).equalsIgnoreCase("mymail@gmail.com"))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                
                System.out.println(message.getContent());
            }

I want print the content but it simply give me the class name instead of the content.
```

Comment: Try https://javapapers.com/java/receive-email-in-java-using-javamail-gmail-imap-example/